# Why do my photos look fantastic on my HTC One X, but not that good on a PC?

Tags: photos, htc-one-x

The photos I take with my HTC One X look excellent on the phone screen, but when I copy them to a PC or laptop and view them on a larger screen, they don't look nearly as good.

Is HTC employing a filter or enhancement to make the photos look better? Could I do the same to the photos after copying them to my laptop?

Comment: What does "not nearly as good" mean? Colors? Sharpness? Brightness? "not nearly as good" is a bit vague to give a sound answer on.

Comment: Generally when you see an image on a bigger screen, you seems to notice blemishes quite apparently. The pixel density of the phone is greater than your monitor and hence could be this feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, HTC is not *...employing a filter or enhancement to make the photos look better...*.

**Second**, 
This is the color settings of the screens. If you transfer a photo taken from a Sony device camera to a Samsung mobile device, you will see a huge difference. That difference is that you can't see the vividness and cleanliness (i.e. *the beauty* ) you saw in the photo of the Samsung phone.

Explanation: The mobile phones has a [PPI or DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) more than 300 whereas the computer monitors have around 150 - 200. Since you are seeing the pictures in a lesser pixel density while you are viewing them in your PC, you may fell that *they don't look nearly as good.*

If you want the beauty you saw in your phone, use Photoshop or any other photo editing app to increase the colors a little and adjust brightness and/or contrast or curves. Our fellow SE members of [Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) will be glad to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry guys! No offence to Samsung owners!! O:)